# Is it okay for a model to populate its own properties?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, tdd

If I have a model that essentially represents a single row in a database, is it scale-friendly and test-friendly, and all around okay practice to have it populate it's own properties, or should it have its properties injected, the same way you would inject an object?

Example:

```
Class blog {
    $id;
    $title;
    $body;

    public function load($id) {
        // db query to load id, title, body
    }
}
```

OR

```
Class blog {
    $id
    $title
    $body
}

// load blog data into $data, and then...

$blog = new Blog($data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's considered a bad practice to commingle database access inside your model classes directly.  Injecting values is generally preferred.

That said, if you were dead set on doing something like $model->load($id) and having it fetch from a datasource, you could get away with something like:

```
class Model {
    private $_dataProvider;

    // inject data-provider dependency in constructor
    public function __construct($dataProvider){
        $this->_dataProvider = $dataProvider;
    } 

    public function loadById($id){
        $myData = $this->_dataProvider->loadDataById($id);
        $this->setFoo($myData['foo']);
        ...
    } 
}
```

By injecting a data access class, you can pass a mock in for testing, or replace your database with some web service, or whatever.  As long as $dataProvider has a loadDataById() method that takes an int and returns the appropriate data structure, you're good.

Personally, I prefer keep my models nice and focused on representing whatever it is they're modeling.  I rely on external service classes and repositories to load data, inject it into models, and return them.

Comment: I see, so you consider the data access as separate from the business logic in this case?

Comment: Also, say you've adjusted the data within the model....maybe changed the title - do you use the model to save the data, or inject it back into the $dataProvider?

Comment: In that example, the models have a dependency on `dataProvider`. *Can* be bad practice as well.

Comment: @hakre - I agree, it's a design decision to think carefully about.  My key point is that if you're going to create that dependency, make it injectable. johnnietheblack - Yes, some kind of save() method would just proxy to dataProvider::save(), which would take either the object itself of an array of properties as the argument.

Comment: @timdev - So, aside from what I COULD do, what is normal? I know pulling data from a single table and running functions on the data is normal...is that usually split into classes like that? Also, is there a tutorial of some kind that you might recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to de-couple the data storage layer from the models itself, you should make it injectable.

If the models are the data storage abstraction, you don't need to care, you only need to inject the models which then should have defined interfaces so you have the rest of your application testable.

But it merely depends on your needs and your design.

Comment: When you say the data storage abstraction, do you specific just mean the CRUD style functions? For example, the blog class might also have a $blog->url() function...

Comment: I mean the layer that stores the models data into a persistent store (e.g. between HTTP requests).